# Sudden silences in groups

Tags: discourse

We've all experienced a moment where a roomful of people are talking, and suddenly everyone falls silent. Sometimes no one is left talking. Sometimes one person is left talking at the original volume and hence much too loud, and when they realize everyone's listening generally says (as if by obligation), "Wow, everyone just stopped talking..."

Is there any research, perhaps in discourse analysis or psycholinguistics, as to specifically linguistic prompts for this phenomenon?

Comment: Interesting question. Also interesting are the expressions for this very common phenomenon. Several other European languages (at least French and Danish) use expressions meaning ‘an angel passes (through the room)’, based on a Greek phrase that specified the angel as Hermes; Russian, for some reason, says ‘a fool/cop was born’. English doesn’t really have any expression for it at all, though calqued ‘an angel passes’ is occasionally heard.

Comment: I would be inclined to begin by looking into research around the so-called "rhetorical situation," as I think what you're referring to possibly involves the idea of exigence, and perhaps kairos.